# I can't convert int[][] to int[,] and can't define an int[][] array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to solve a challenge on a coding site. The problem is about int matrixes. I am using c# language.I need to create a function that takes a parameter as `int[][]` (integer matrix) and also return `int[][]` (another integer matrix). Starting of problem (the empty function given to me) is like that

```
int[][] boxBlur(int[][] image) {

}
```

and this is what i tried so far

```
int[][] boxBlur(int[][] image) {

int pixelLength = image[0].Length - 2;
int[][] newBox = new int[pixelLength][pixelLength];
int pixelSum = 0;   
int c = 0;

  for(int t = 0; t<pixelLength; t++)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i<pixelLength; i++)
    {
        for(int j = t; j < 3 + t ; j++)
        {
            for(int k = i; k < i+3 ; k++)
            {
                pixelSum += image[j][k];
            }
        } 
        newBox[t][i] = pixelSum / 9;
    }
 }    
 return newBox;
}
```

Now i don't have any problem with algorithm, probably it will work but the problem is that i can't define an Array like `int[][]`. It gives an error like `Cannot implicitly convert type int to int[][]` and when i try to create this array like

`int[,] newBox = new int[pixelLength,pixelLength];`

it also gives error because it says the return type is wrong and i can't change the return type so i need to define a matrix exactly like `int[][]`.

Is there any way to do it or do i need to try another way?

Comment: Another way.  Read the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) to find out how to properly create a jagged array.

Comment: `[,]` and `[][]` aren't equivalent. If the problem explicitly requires jagged arrays, then use jagged arrays.

Comment: Also, `newBox[t][i] = pixelSum / 9;` will fail since you never instantiated `newBox[t]`

Comment: The posted code and the described error don't match. Your problem lies here: `new int[pixelLength][pixelLength];`. That expression doesn't make any sense, you have an invalid rank specifier. This is probably due to a deep misunderstanding of what jagged arrays really are and how to use them.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know anything as jagged arrays. Seems like my problem is about that. Thank you all. A good question to take a question ban pff...

Comment: @InBetween "That expression doesn't make any sense" is more a shortcoming of C#, it could/should make perfect sense.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tend to disagree because it somehow 1) defeats the purpose of (non) jagged arrays and 2) having arrays initialized to something else than the type's default value seems somehow inconsistent. I do understand your point of view though, my view is more of an opinion.

Comment: And in my opinion, both `matrix[n][m]` and `jagged[n][]` should be possible/allowed. But I don't care enough to make it a feature request.

Comment: If you're writing an imagine manipulation algorithm, you almost certainly intend to be using a multidimensional array instead of a jagged array.

Comment: @willaien - why? For one thing, `[,]` tends to be slower. But having separate lines might be useful in by itself.

Comment: Unless performance is an issue, I would suggest sticking to the methodology that more closely matches the problem at hand. An image is a 2d grid, meaning that a multidimensional array more closely represents the actual data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int[][]` is a *jagged array*, or in other words, an *array of arrays*.

When you see a `int[]`, you understand it as an array of integers. That is, every "slot" of the array holds and integer. An array of arrays is exactly the same, except that every slot holds an array.

Once you understand that, it should make perfect sense why the correct way to initialize your jagged array is:

```
int[][] newBox = new int[pixelLength][];
```

Now you've said that `newBox` is an array of int arrays: `newBox[0]` is of type `int[]`, `newBox[1]` is of type `int[]`, etc. Because the default value of an array, like any other reference type, is `null`, the value of `newBox[0]`, `newBox[1]`, etc. is `null`; you need to initialize each and every one of them.

The advantage of jagged arrays is, of course, that each `int[]` can be the size you wish, hence the name *jagged* array.

So what you are essentially missing, once you initialize your jagged array correctly, is initalizing each and everyone of the `int[]` arrays before using them. You can do this inside the adequate loop.

Carrying on from here should be easy.

An interesting test to verify if you've understood everything correctly is initalizing and correctly filling up all the values of the following type:

```
int[][][] myHeadHurtsArray;
```

Answer (score 4):

`int[][]` and `int[,]` are two different things. The first is [Jagged Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), the second is [Multidimensional Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

When initializing jagged array you can give only the array length, not the length of all the arrays in it:

```
int[][] newBox = new int[pixelLength][];
```

And insert new array each time:

```
newBox[index] = new int[size];
```